# Create custom TextStyle class on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How can I create a custom TextStyle class in flutter? For example I have several buttons and want the text inside to all be the same fontSize and color but I don't want to repeat the TextStyle inside of each Text widget, but instead create something such as CustomTextStyle that I could use in the place of the TextStyle itself.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a separate class names CustomTextStyle and add the styles inside them like:

```
class CustomTextStyle {
  static const TextStyle nameOfTextStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 24,
    color: Colors.green,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );
}
```

Now you can use it in Text widget like:

```
Text('Lorem Ipsum',
   style: CustomTextStyle.nameOfTextStyle,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To define your button or text style globally, you need to use theme.

For example, you can define a custom theme for `TextButton` :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this:

1. Using Theme:

   You can declare multiple TextStyles separately in Theme based on widgets, for e.g. `AppBar`'s `TitleTextTheme`, `AppBar`'s `ToolbarTextTheme`, `Button`'s `TextTheme`, General `TextTheme` for the whole app, or based on `ThemeMode`, for e.g. Dark Mode or Light mode, you can combine these two Widgets based and ThemeModes based as well.

   To do this, Create a class called `ThemeModel` for example, Create the `ThemeData` Variables in it in which you'll declare these TextThemes and use it in your `MaterialApp` in `main.dart` as

   ```
   MaterialApp(
     ...,
     theme: ThemeModel().lightMode,
     darkTheme: ThemeModel().darkMode,
   )
   ```
2. Using a Custom Text Widget.

   ```
   const CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
   final String text;
   const CustomText(this.text, {Key? key}): super(key:key);  

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Text(
       text,
       style: TextStyle(
         color: YourColor,
         fontSize: YourSize,
         fontWeight: YourFontWeight
       ),
     );
   ```

   and use it as,

   ```
   ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: (){},
     child: CustomText('Click Me'),
   )
   ```

   This way the `TextStyle` will remain same wherever you'll use this widget.
3. Using Custom `TextStyle`:

   ```
   class CustomTextStyle {
     static const TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(
       color: YourColor,
       fontSize: YourSize,
       fontWeight: YourFontWeight
     );
   }
   ```

   and, use it as:

   ```
   ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: (){},
     child: Text('Click Me', 
       style: CustomTextStyle.textStyle,
     ),
   )
   ```

Hope, you understand that every one of these methods have their own utility and can be customized way further to make your app development easy.