# Flutter: Add custom color to existing theme

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using Flutters built-in `themes` like this:

```
 return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            primaryColor: const Color(0xFF5E975A),
            bottomAppBarColor: const Color(0xff282828),
            // ... And so on
          ),
```

As you can see I am modifying the existing `theme` with `copyWith`. Now let's say I want a certain button to always have the `Color(0xFFFF0000)`. Is there a way to add a new key to the existing theme?

Something like this:

```
ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            ...
          ).addKey(myCustomColor: const Color(0xFFFF0000))
```

If not, what is the **best-practice way** to define my custom color? I feel like just declaring a global static variable is not the intended way to implement this.

Comment: Theme consists of the properties provided by `ThemeData` in which all the possible fields related to all the widgets have already been defined. For custom one, either you can override the default `ThemeData` to make some custom keys or you should make a global `ButtonStyle`/Custom `Button`, for this, see my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053982/8244632).

Comment: You can create a separate widget for that certain button with the color you want and simply reuse that button wherever you need it. That's how I would approach this problem. I am not aware of any custom color functionality in ThemeData, but I guess this solution would work for you just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still finding the best practice way of defining ThemeData. For now, I have already used 2 ways to achieve the custom colors:

### 1 Use [Extension](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

```
// use it with "Theme.of(context).myCustomColor"
extension CustomThemeDataExt on ThemeData {
  Color get myCustomColor {
    if(brightness == Brightness.light){
      return Color(0xFFFF0000);
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
}

...
```

### 2 Define a custom theme

```
// use it with "CustomTheme.of(context).myCustomColor"
class CustomTheme {
  final BuildContext context;

  const CustomTheme(this.context);

  static CustomTheme of(BuildContext context) => CustomTheme(context);

  Color get myCustomColor {
    if(Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light){
      return Color(0xFFFF0000);
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Both need to import the relative file.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the first solution. This seems a little more elegant than random global variables. It would be nice to have an official take from Flutter on this tho.

Comment: For future readers: Flutter 3 has an out-of-the-box answer to this question but for older versions this is the correct approach.

Comment: @JosipDomazet and yet you didn't bother to tell what the solution is lol

Comment: @Boni Have a look at my answer to my own question, it adresses just that.

Answer (score 7):

**Update for Flutter 3:**

Flutter has answered this exact question in the newest version of Flutter. You can now create `ThemeExtensions`.

This can look something like this (after defining your `ThemeExtension`):

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    extensions: <ThemeExtension<dynamic>>[
      CustomColors.light,
    ],
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    extensions: <ThemeExtension<dynamic>>[
      CustomColors.dark,
    ],
  ),
  // other parameters...
);
```

In the future there will be definitely more information about this but for now have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/flutter-3-how-to-extend-themedata-56b8923bf1aa). I took the sample from there.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I also found the official video that talks about it: [ThemeExtensions | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-szcYzFVao)